# MKmapView Delegate: regionDidChangeAnimated and mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I`m trying to add an annotation when the map is loaded and the region did change:

How Can I do a mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap and when is done a regionDidChangeAnimated??

Thanks

Tony

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but you seem to be going on the right track. Are you asking because it is not working?

```
mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap
```

and

```
regionDidChangeAnimated
```

seem to be the right methods to do what you are trying to do.

Add the annotations in those methods with

```
[myMKMapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```